# Symfony couldn't autowire Response service into controller method

Tags: php, symfony

Trying to inject `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response` into controller method

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Attribute\AsController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

#[AsController]
class TestController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route(path: 'test', name: 'test', methods: ['GET'])]
    public function test(Request $request, Response $response) : Response
    {
        return $response->setContent("Hello!");
    }
}
```

But get an error

```
Could not resolve argument $response of &quot;App\Controller\TestController::test()&quot;, maybe you forgot
        to register the controller as a service or missed tagging it with the controller.service_arguments;?
        (500 Internal Server Error)
```

Debug `php bin/console debug:autowiring --all` shows, that container have `Response`

```
...
 Request represents an HTTP request.
 Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request

 Response represents an HTTP response.
 Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
...
```

Why request injected, but Response not?

Comment: Have you tried `php bin/console cache:clear`?

Comment: @Bossman yes, doesn't help

Comment: Response is not a service so it cannot be injected.  You might think that since Request is injected then Response can be as well but Request is not a service either.  The request object is create in index.php and added to the controller method via something called an Controller Argument Resolver.  As the answer below indicates, you are responsible (pun intended) from creating the Response object.

Comment: @Cerad But the Response is present in the container why is it not wiring then? 
All classes represented in the container can be injected or not?

Comment: Neither the Response nor the Request are services and neither are in the container.  Items injected into a controller's method are not not necessarily services nor do they all come from the container.  Perhaps this oldie but still goodie [Symfony article](https://symfony.com/doc/current/introduction/http_fundamentals.html) might help.

Comment: Your error message is actually a bit strange as it seems to indicate that your controller does not have the controller.service_arguments which it should have automatically as long as you are using autowire/autoconfig.  So you would still get the error even if there was a Response service.  Does `bin/console debug:container TestController` show the tag and a call to setContainer?

Comment: @Cerad debug shows  
`Service ID       App\Controller\TestController`  
`Tags             controller.service_arguments`
`Calls            setContainer`
`Autowired        yes`
`Autoconfigured   yes`

Comment: I can't explain the results of your `debug:autowiring` command but unless you have somehow explicitly defined a Response service, `debug:container Response` will not show a service.  But just for kicks, try injecting some random actual service (maybe `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security`) and see if the error goes away.

Comment: @Cerad I tried to inject `Serializer` , but it works only with `SerializerInterface`

Comment: This might be a good time to take a step back and re-read the service container section in the docs.  Maybe work through a few of the examples.  Especially the stuff on aliases and multiple implementations of the same interface.  How the container works does make sense once you get past the fundamentals.  Until then, it can be a pain.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to inject a response. You should create your own instance:

```php
#[AsController]
class TestController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route(path: 'test', name: 'test', methods: ['GET'])]
    public function test(Request $request) : Response
    {
        $response = new Response();

        return $response->setContent("Hello!");
    }
}
```